# How to reply or comment on threads in the Linux Kernel Mailing List?

Tags: git, linux-kernel, email-client, mailing-list

I am having some trouble replying and comment on threads in the Linux Kernel Mailing List, I have submitted some patches and then I have received some comments from reviews, I tried to reply to them by just prefixing the subject line with "Re:"

I have first I made some changes and commit them using:

```
git commit -a
```

then I have formatted the commit using:

```
git format-patch master..fix-warning
```

after that I have edit it the output from:

```
Subject: [PATCH] block: Removed a warning while compiling with a cross compiler for parisc
```

to:

```
Subject: Re: [PATCH] block: Removed a warning while compiling with a cross compiler for parisc
```

after that I have send it using:

```
git send-email --to linux-block@vger.kernel.org --cc linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org name-of-the-patch.patch
```

I have allready set up the .gitconfig file with following configuration:

```
smtpEncryption = ssl
smtpServer = smtp.gmail.com
smtpUser = my-email-address@gmail.com
smtpServerPort = 465
```

It did not worked and what happened is that instead of replying to the reviewer, I end up creating a new thread in LKML... I know the path that I have taken does not seems right for replying to a commit lol, before doing all that, I looked into the FAQ in LKML website, for how to reply to comments I have not find an answer, I have google it, and also I have not find any answer then I tried to press on "reply all" in Gmail App on apple OS it did not worked too...

could someone please direct me to the correct article which talking about replying and comment in the LKML, or give me some tips!
I would appreciate it.

Comment: You need to use good MUA. You haven’t provided any useful pieces of information in your Q.

Comment: thanks for your comment, what kind of information should i provide, do you mean the link to the patch or link to the thread in the lkml or other thing @0andriy

Comment: @learning: "MUA" probably means "Mail User Agent" - the program you use for send and receive mail messages. Normally, such program provides you a "Reply all" button, by pressing it you got a mail template with all fields correctly filled. You just need to enter content of the reply, and press "Send". BTW, you use tag "email-client" probably for denote the problem with such client, but your post actually contain no information about the email client you use.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, it's me who updated the tags.

Comment: @0andriy I have edit the post, I hope it have now some useful information

Comment: If you send a new version of the patch (after addressing review comments) you actually must to create another thread and bump the version. Something like `git format-patch -v2 ...` in your case. Otherwise, replying to the thread is done by linking thru `Message-Id` (see RFC-2822 for the details).

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you for your commit now it is a bit clear to me, I have edit the post, I hope it have now some useful information, I googled "Mail User Agent for lkml" I got some information and that it is good to use mutt email-client

Comment: @0andriy that was really helpful thank you very much

Comment: Well, the question becomes much clear now. I have added "git" tag for denote that you are trying to use `git` for send mails with patches. I am not an expert in email fields, but according to [documentation for git-send-email](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-send-email) I would try to use `--in-reply-to` option. You could always test different sending options in compound with `--confirm=always`, so you could be able to check resulted mail and its fields before the sending.